# mysql connection using phonegap in android

Tags: android, mysql, cordova

I want to know how to Display data from Mysql database using PHP with a Phonegap android application using webservices.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly put a php page into phonegap application. First you have to create a web service to get your data. And then create a html page which has javascript code to call your web service and display data. You could use jQuery to invoke web services simpler than raw javascript.